# Mongo Multiple Level Aggregate Group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following data after unwinding in an aggregate:

```
let workOrders = [
    {customer: 'A', job: 'Apple', chemical: {name: 'Chem A', quantity: 500}},
    {customer: 'A', job: 'Banana', chemical: {name: 'Chem B', quantity: 400}},
    {customer: 'A', job: 'Banana', chemical: {name: 'Chem C', quantity: 300}},
    {customer: 'B', job: 'Cherry', chemical: {name: 'Chem A', quantity: 200}}
]
```

Output needed:

```
[
  {
    customer: 'A',
    jobs: [
      {
        job: 'Apple',
        chemicals: [
          {name: 'Chem A', quantity: 500}
        ]
      },
      {
        job: 'Banana',
        chemicals: [
          {name: 'Chem B', quantity: 400},
          {name: 'Chem C', quantity: 300}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    customer: 'B',
    jobs: [
      {
        job: 'Cherry',
        chemicals: [
          {name: 'Chem A', quantity: 200}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I understand how to use group and group it by customer first, but then I don't understand how to make the nested chemicals array without messing up the initial customer group.

I tried something like this but it doesn't like the inner $push.

`{
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$customer",
      "groups": {
          $push: {
              "group_data": "$customer",
              "group_count": {$sum: "$customer"},
              "group_child": {
                  $push: {
                      "group_data":  "$job",
                      "group_count": {$sum: "$job"},
                      "group_children": {
                          $push: {
                              "group_data": "$chemical.name",
                              "group_count": {$sum: "$chemical.name"}
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }`

Also would like to add the total of quantity per Customer and per Job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make nested chemicals you just need two `$group` stages:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { customer: "$customer", job: "$job" },
            chemicals: { $push: "$chemical" },
            jobTotal: { $sum: "$chemical.quantity" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.customer",
            jobs: { $push: { job: "$_id.job", jobTotal: "$jobTotal", chemicals: "$chemicals" } },
            customerTotal: { $sum: "$jobTotal" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            customer: "$_id.customer",
            customerTotal: 1,
            jobs: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CefTc6e6YHj)

Comment: If I wanted to get the chemical.quantity sum and average per each customer and job, how could I achieve that?  Need Customer A total sum = 1200, but also need job Apple total sum = 500, job Banana total sum = 700?

Comment: @user1779362 modified my answer

Comment: I ended up doing 3 groups, using all 3 as _id, then 2 then 1, stacking the array inside as I go.  That way I can grab more data off the collection that I want underneath each chemical. Your example taught me what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
             _id:{job:'$job'},
             chemicals:{$push:'$chemical'},
             docObj:{$first:'$$CURRENT'}

            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id:{customer:'$docObj.customer'},
                jobs:{$push:{job:'$_id.job',chemicals:'$chemicals'}}

            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
               customer:'$_id.customer',
               jobs:1,
               _id:0
            }
        },

    ]



);
```